# How do I find a url in a string closest to a substring(after using stripos)? (PHP)

Tags: php, string, substring

I'm working with an html string and trying to find the closest url in position to the substring.

```
if (stripos($theemailmessage,'substring') !== FALSE ) 
{
    $indicatornumber = '1';
}
```

So stripos() should give me the position of this substring inside the string.  How would I go about searching for values within a url from here?  I'm assuming it would be something traversing the string positions looking for `http://` , but I'm really not sure which function I should be using.

**There are many URLs in the document that I am searching for, I'm searching for the one closest to the string position.  Actually, I want to search to see if the string is inside an anchor tag first, but I figured I'd start by learning how to search for the closest url, and then refine from there.**

Comment: See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/the-problem-with-urls.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Unfortunately, I didn't see anything about finding a url with distance relative to a substring within the larger string.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

> preg_match('/http\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/',$str, $url);
>
> echo $url[0];

Comment: No, there are many URLs in the larger string that I'm looking for.  This also doesn't seem to take into account the current position in the string where I found the substring.

Comment: Well then just use the above regex for the characters after your substring...no?

Comment: That will find the next URL after your substring. If that is not what you want you should probably explain you question a bit better...because I don't get it :-)

Comment: url may also be before the substring

Comment: Well then that would be the whole string wouldnt it? If you are trying to find a url within a certain distance of a substring, then just make a new string of that part (ie. substring(position of substring + - distance)) and then perform the above regex on that object...

Answer (score 0):

you have several options to implement this. use preg_replace function or use parse_url function.

```
$tempText = "hello.. how are you?? are you keeping well?? please checkout this url http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehuwoGVLyhg&feature=topvideos";

print_r(parse_url($tempText,PHP_URL_PATH));
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because there are many URLs in the larger string function that I'm working with.  This also doesn't take into consideration the position of the found substring.

Answer (score 0):

Good luck finding a regexp to match URLs, but suppose you have one.

Then,

```
preg_match_all($url_regexp, $source, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Take a look in `$matches` and you will have every URL plus its position. Iterate over these to find which is closest to your substring position. Make sure that you account for the length of the matches and your substring.

Comment: This looks perfect!  I think all of the urls will be in anchor tags so I'm assuming I can reg src=" up until another quote".  or src=' up until another single quote'.  Okay, so source is the larger string, and then I'd create a loop to find closest offset to the position of the substring match?  This sounds perfect!